# How to select a specific d3 node group element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 v4 force simulation with several nodes. Each node has a group. When I mouse over one of the elements of that group(an invisible circle) I want one of the other elements (the red circle on that specific node only which I gave an id of "backcircle") to do something. Currently this is what I have, but it does it to all nodes not just the one I'm hovering over's element.

```
this.node = this.d3Graph.selectAll(null)
.data(this.props.nodes)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes");

this.node.append("circle")
.attr("id", "backCircle")
.attr("r", 60)
.attr("fill", "red")


this.node.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.img })
        .attr("height", 60)
        .attr("width", 60)
        .attr("x", -30)
        .attr("y", -30)


          this.node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 60)
            .attr("fill", "transparent")
            .on( 'mouseenter', function(d) {
              d.r = 65;
              this.node.select("#backCircle")
              .transition()
              .attr("r", 80);

            }.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else, two important tips:

1. Do not use `"transparent"` in an SVG.
2. IDs are **unique**. So, use classes instead (or select by the tag name)

Back to your question:

There are several ways of selecting the circle element based on a sibling circle element. The first one is going up the DOM and down again, using `this.parentNode`. The second one, if you know exactly the sequence of the siblings, is using `previousSibling`.

In the following demos, I have 3 elements per group: a circle, a text and a rectangle. Hovering over the rectangle will select the circle.

First, the option with `this.parentNode`. in your case:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).select(".backCircle")
```

Hover over the squares:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [50, 150, 250];
var g = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d + ",75)"
  });

g.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "backCircle")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("fill", "teal")

g.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("FOO");

g.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "firebrick")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select(".backCircle")
      .transition()
      .attr("r", 50)
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select(".backCircle")
      .transition()
      .attr("r", 40)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Then, the option with `previousSibling` (here, you don't even need to set a class). In your case:

```
d3.select(this.previousSibling.previousSibling)
```

Hover over the squares:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [50, 150, 250];
var g = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d + ",75)"
  });

g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .attr("fill", "teal")

g.append("text")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("FOO");

g.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .style("fill", "firebrick")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    d3.select(this.previousSibling.previousSibling)
      .transition()
      .attr("r", 50)
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    d3.select(this.previousSibling.previousSibling)
      .transition()
      .attr("r", 40)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

PS: Have in mind that, since I'm not using an object, there is no need for `bind(this)` in my snippets.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. When you say don't use "transparent", is it okay to use "opacity" "0"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to select the node that is firing the mouseenter event from within its handler.

```
      this.node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 60)
        .attr("fill", "transparent")
        .on( 'mouseenter', function(d) {
          var mouseenterNode = d3.select(this) 
          mouseenterNode.attr("r", 65);
          mouseenterNode.select("#backCircle")
          .transition()
            .attr("r", 80);
        }.bind(this))
```

Comment: This was a good idea, but when I tried it it did nothing at all.

Comment: If you add a working fiddle to your question I will take another look.